# How to fetch eligible Payment and Shipping method in REST API magento 2?

Tags: api, payment-methods, shipping-methods, rest-api

Fetch eligible shipping methods and Payment methods in Magento 2 Rest API.

- In case of if i have a customer id.
- In case of if it is a guest user.

Comment: I have a project where I'm doing it https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native. I currently don't have time to put a big well-structured answer, but you can contact me directly so I can answer your questions in a conversational way. You can find my contact on the github.